# What's the difference between Screen.invalidate() and Screen.invalidateLayout()

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-jde

```
void invalidate() 
      Invalidates the entire screen.


void invalidateLayout() 
      Invalidates this screen's layout (including all controlled fields).
```

The javadoc doesn't help much. Could you tell me why do we need invalidateLayout()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how you build your UI, you may be interested in **invalidating**, or **updating layout**, when you want the display to change.

If you have a UI that's composed of standard `Field` objects, like `TextField`, or `ButtonField`, or `BrowserField`, without much customization, then the work of defining how the UI looks is mostly in how those fields are *laid out*.  *Layout* refers to setting the size of fields, and their position.

Sometimes, you'll have a UI where you need to deal at a lower level.  For example, you may do some custom painting, which involves drawing lines, filling areas, drawing gradients, etc.  This work is normally done in a `Field` object's `paint()` method.  Sometimes, you also have drawing code in other places like `drawFocus()` or `paintBackground()`.

If you want to trigger repainting, which calls your custom `paint()` method, then you want to use `invalidate()` to make that happen.

If you want to trigger a new layout, which arranges child fields with certain sizes, or positions, then `invalidateLayout()` can be used for that.

However, I will note that `invalidateLayout()` is a method in the `Screen` class.  If you use a RIM `Screen` subclass, like `MainScreen` or `FullScreen`, then they come with their own top level *delegate* `Manager` objects.  I believe that calling `Screen.invalidateLayout()` will trigger the `sublayout()` method on that built-in `Manager` to be called.  That may not be what you really want.

Unless you implement your own `Screen` subclass like this:

```java
public class MyScreen extends Screen {

   public MyScreen() {
       super(new MyCustomManager());
   }
}
```

you probably aren't implementing the code (including `sublayout()`) for that delegate manager yourself.

I have found that when I want to force `sublayout()` to be called again, I trigger that with the [updateLayout() method](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Field.html#updateLayout%28%29), not `invalidateLayout()`.  Also, as opposed to `invalidateLayout()`, which is a method of the `Screen`, `updateLayout` is available for all `Manager` and `Field` classes, so you can choose just the specific part of the UI element *tree* that you want to refresh.  But, that's just my experience.

[Here's some comments on the BlackBerry forums on this topic](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/updateLayout-and-invalidate-in-Manager/td-p/1878907)